# IntelliJ VCS is combining projects on GitHub

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

Every project I now create in IntelliJ is getting mixed up with a previous one when I try to push it to GitHub.  They all end up in a single repo. I was previously able to share the projects and commit and push without problem.  Now, something has changed and I don’t know how to fix it.

I created a new project checkGitPush to trace the problem and find the following issues.  “Enable Version Control” did not show up on the VCS menu.  I can commit locally, but when I try to Share the Project to GitHub, I get this message:

```
Project is Already on GitHub
Following remotes are already on GitHub
```

(It then lists three separate projects)

When I look on GitHub, all these projects are getting put into the bottom-most project listed on the message.

Any suggestions are appreciated.
I am on a Windows laptop with IntellJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no .git folder in any parent directory of the one you are using for your new project:

```
c:\
  path\
    to\
      .git
      some\
        new_project\
```

Here new_project would be part of the Git repository located in `C:\path\to`, and possibly linked to a GitHub repo: type `git remote -v` in command line to confirm it.

Removing that `.git\` folder (or at least moving it, saving it elsewhere) would allow you to create an independent project, which could be linked to its own GitHub repository, following for example "[CheatSheet - Setup Github on Visual Studio Code](http://www.notyourdadsit.com/blog/2018/4/3/cheatsheet-setup-github-on-visual-studio-code)"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you create new projects inside an existing git repository. So IDE detects there is a git root above the project and registers it. As a result, new files become part of the existing repository.